# Is there an EPSG code appropriate for locally projected data?

Tags: coordinate-system

I often use GIS to track some very local things. Particularly, mapping on microscope slides works quite well. These obviously cannot be georeferenced in any meaningful way.

Perhaps the right thing to do is just not to set a CRS, but I'd like to remove ambiguity any way I can. Any ideas?

Comment: If your microscope slides are rectangular I would have thought simple Cartesian coordinates with no coordinate reference system would be the way to go.

Comment: GeoServer uses epsg:404000 for an unknown cartesian coordinate system